# how to calculate the average of each string

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm having a hard time converting the ASCII counterpart of each char in string,
**my objective is to convert the average of each word
for example:**
if the user input "love" the code will return 54,
the thing is this code is inside a loop and if the user input for example;
**Word no.1: "love"
Word no.2: "love"**
the code should return;
**54
54**
but my code returns **108**
i guess the problem is in this part `sum += static_cast<int>(compute - 64);` but I don't know the right approach for my problem

```
 for(int x = 1; x <= numofinput; x++){
            cout << "Word no. " << x << ": ";
            getline(cin,words);
            
            for(auto compute : words){
                if(isalpha(compute)){
                    compute = toupper(compute);
                    sum += static_cast<int>(compute - 64); 
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why not `cout` immediately rather than add the value to `sum`?

Comment: `"Word no. "` and `getline(cin,words);`  ... Do you want to read _one_ word or a list of _words_? `auto compute` makes `compute` a `char`. Is that what you expect?

Comment: I tried to immediately print it but it doesn't return the expected output

Comment: Don't use magic numbers. Instead of `64`, write `'@'` - or better: `'A' - 1`

Comment: yes Mr. Lyngmo that's what I expect

Comment: "_yes that's what I expect_" - Ok, so do you want the user to enter _one_ word or a bunch of words? Note that you should cast the `char` to `unsigned char` before you use any of the `cctype` functions like `isalpha` and `toupper`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo single word only I just put getline incase the user inputs a string with whitespace

Comment: `std::cin >> word;` would read one word (and skip the whitespaces)

Comment: You're summing everything and then printing the final sum when you should be doing it for each word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `sum = 0;` for each word you do calculations on.
There are also a number of other small issues that I've commented on in this example:

```cpp
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    int numofinput = 2;

    for(int x = 1; x <= numofinput; x++) {
        std::cout << "Word no. " << x << ": ";

        if(std::string word; std::cin >> word) { // read one word
            int sum = 0;                         // only count the sum for this word

            // auto& if you'd like to show it in uppercase later:
            for(auto& compute : word) {

                // use unsigned char's with the cctype functions:
                auto ucompute = static_cast<unsigned char>(compute);

                if(std::isalpha(ucompute)) {
                    compute = static_cast<char>(std::toupper(ucompute));
                    sum += compute - ('A' - 1);  // 'A' - 1 instead of 64
                }
            }

            std::cout << "stats for " << word << '\n'
                      << "sum: " << sum << '\n'
                      << "avg: " << static_cast<unsigned>(sum) / word.size() << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```